# Problems installing powerline fonts on macOS 10.12

Tags: terminal, macos, font

I'm pretty new with MacOS and Macbooks in general. I've been a unix user for a long time and right now I'm trying to install the **patched powerline fonts** to use with OhMyZsh, VIM and the like but I'm running into some issues getting it to properly work.

I've followed a couple different guides but I'm always getting the same **error in that some of the special icons/characters show up correctly on the terminal while some others don't** and that pretty much screws everything up.

Here's the latest guide I followed (and the simplest one): [powerline/fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) and here's a screenshot of how my terminal currently looks like:

[image]

The fonts do seem to be installed as they show up in the font book.

**Q: What can I do to so all icons/characters show up correctly?**

Answer (score 5):

Fixed. It was me just being dumb.

Everything was properly installed and working but I realized that iTerm2 and the stock Terminal app were set to use a different kind of font so that's why it wasn't displaying some characters.

Going into iTerm2's settings and manually overriding the fonts fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue today, basically to enable the Powerline fonts from iTerm2, just go over to Preferences > Profiles > Text and check the box for "Use built-in Powerline glyphs".